# error UrlHelper and mono

Tags: mono, castle-monorail, urlhelper

In my views (velocity template mode) I call `$Url.Link` helper, in Visual Studio with cassini it work but when I deploy my webapp on mono/nginx/ubuntu url are well not formed, I get only the controler's action path.

it's seems it come from `Url.For` method and its compatibility with monoserv

Comment: This will be quite hard to solve without at least a failing test...

Comment: it doesn't crash when I run my wepapp on vs my urls are area/controler/action/id/ and when I run on monoserv Url.link give me area/controler/action.rails

Comment: maybe it's a known bug of the mono implementation where my routing pages are not added.

Comment: Are you using the latest version of Mono? Can you try running Monorail's tests on your version of Mono?

Comment: last version of mono and monorail too, "all" the site is working except the Url.For, I tried moving my "routes initialisation" from application_start to the action of the controler and it doesn't work too.

Comment: Can you try running Monorail's tests on your version of Mono?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I remember having to replace the DefaultUrlBuilder to make an app run on mono. I had to override the ConvertRouteParams method to create a Hashtable without the StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase. HTH

Checkout line 397: [DefaultUrlBuilder](https://github.com/castleproject/MonoRail/blob/master/MR2/src/Castle.MonoRail.Framework/Services/DefaultUrlBuilder.cs)

Comment: Great I will try this in the week to confirm that I had to use another method for the url builder but if I can use the default monorail UrlBuilder I prefer